# Hubble vs JWST telescope

Tags: james-webb-telescope, hubble

Can you quantify how much better JWST is compared to Hubble?
For instance, from what distance can each "see" (differentiate) a sun-like star?

Maybe there are other measures.

Comment: Potentially helpful link: https://www.jwst.nasa.gov/content/about/faqs/faq.html#sharp

Comment: Hubble and JWST are designed for different wavelengths, Hubble for visible light, JWST for red to mid IR. So you may compare resolution and sensitivity only for red light detectable by both telescopes.

Comment: I think, the images just released at the press conference and at https://www.nasa.gov/webbfirstimages (where similar hubble images are referenced) gives a very good visual indication.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the redshift very far stars and galaxies are not detectable within the range of visible light but as infrared. The JWST is built for longer wavelengths than the Hubble so it can "look" farther.

Hubble could not "look" farther than about 400 million years after the big-bang, but the JWST may look to about only 180 million years after the big-bang.

You asked for distances and not for the "age" of light. I am sorry, it is not possible to calculate a well defined distance from the age of light.

Comment: This is a really good point. Still,  I think my example is about something a bit different. Namely, I asked about diffraction limit (this is the word). But it is true, that in different distances, the red shift will cause it to be infrarred or near. And yet, I think there might be such limit for the distance, if we consider both the redshift and we assume main class star of sun's radius. Let me know if I am wrong. It would be interesting to know this, even ignoring the red shift. Though, not practical

Comment: @user2679290 The angular resolution of JWST's [NIRCam](https://www.as.arizona.edu/nircam) is 0.07 arcsec at 2 microns. That corresponds to the angular diameter of the Sun at a distance of ~0.4334 light-years.

Comment: In visible light (at wavelengths near 500 nm) the combination of the Hubble telescope plus its highest resolution cameras achieve an angular resolution of about 0.04 arc seconds.